# What is the "standard way" for adding getter and setter to Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript

I need to create `getter` and `setter` properties (ES5) on the prototype of an object. At the moment I am using the following code, it works, but I would like to know:

- Is this a "standard way" to do it?
- Can `Object.defineProperties()` be used instead?
- Any better options/approches?

I am targeting ES5, vanilla JS only, browser enviroment.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/0yLotg35/

```
function Color() {}
Color.prototype = {
    _name: '',
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    },
    set name(value) {
        this._name = value;
    },
    _readOnly: true,
    get readOnly() {
        return this._readOnly;
    }
};

var myColor = new Color();
myColor.name = 'red';
alert(myColor.name);

alert(myColor.readOnly);
myColor.readOnly = false;
alert(myColor.readOnly); // value it is not changed
```

Comment: Does what you have not work in any ES5 environment you have tried it? [That's what I know as the standard](http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/object-literals-es5.html)

Comment: @JuanMendes the code I am trying it works fine in ES5 env. my target is Chrome and FF latest version only. Thanks for time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That is the standard way for an object literal.http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/object-literals-es5.html
2. Yes, you could use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) if you need to add properties dynamically
3. Why do you need an alternative? It's hard to suggest something without knowing the use case

   - Create methods for getters and setters instead of properties?
   - Use [defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

## [defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
  "property1": {
    value: true,
    writable: true
  },
  "property2": {
    value: "Hello",
    writable: false
  }
});
```

## [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
function Archiver() {
  var temperature = null;
  var archive = [];

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'temperature', {
    get: function() {
      console.log('get!');
      return temperature;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      temperature = value;
      archive.push({ val: temperature });
    }
  });

  this.getArchive = function() { return archive; };
}

var arc = new Archiver();
arc.temperature; // 'get!'
arc.temperature = 11;
arc.temperature = 13;
arc.getArchive(); // [{ val: 11 }, { val: 13 }]
```

## Getters and setter on the prototype

```js
function Archiver() {
  // Can't define the array on the prototype or it would be shared by instances
  this._archive = [];
}

Archiver.prototype =  {
  _temperature: null,
  getArchive: function() { 
    return this._archive;
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Archiver.prototype, 'temperature', {
  get: function() {
    return this._temperature;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    this._temperature = value;
    this._archive.push({ val: value });
  }
});

var arc = new Archiver();
arc.temperature; // 'get!'
arc.temperature = 11;
arc.temperature = 13;
console.log(arc.getArchive()); // [{ val: 11 }, { val: 13 }]

var arc2 = new Archiver();
arc2.temperature; // 'get!'
arc2.temperature = 10;
arc2.temperature = 15;
console.log(arc2.getArchive()); // [{ val: 10 }, { val: 15 }]
```

Comment: Many thanks, would you be able to expand your answer, adding an example of the use of Object.defineProperty() with prototype? Regarding the alternative mainly for curiosity, I would be also interested to create methods too. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Thanks for adding an example, just a note, the example seems to add property directly on the object and not on its prototype as Object.defineProperty(this,...) should be instead Object.defineProperty(this.prototype, ....)?

Comment: @GibboK Since you asked so nicely :) I've added an example of doing the same thing using getters/setters on the prototype. Beware that writes always happen on the instance, not on the prototype.